# Why would someone use 1-of-1 multisig?

Tags: multi-signature

Today I noticed a transaction that spends a bunch of 1-of-1 multisig P2WSH inputs:
[675b106c71f110ebca9e6435f49508a07b45d40d38e237d02b89e5506f3b136b](https://mempool.space/tx/675b106c71f110ebca9e6435f49508a07b45d40d38e237d02b89e5506f3b136b)

For example, the first input has this script in the witness:

```
OP_PUSHNUM_1
OP_PUSHBYTES_33 031f1c516fc9362202883b24fd92e6548776a8f1701baca38b63bbe635da8a82f7
OP_PUSHNUM_1
OP_CHECKMULTISIG
```

I then wrote a script to find more of these transactions, and it turns out in the last 1000 blocks there were 3883 transactions spending 1-of-1 multisig inputs. This one spends over 30 BTC: [4d8a475e7a0433ef84baec9ec941342cb31d4194b42dedccdc4503e4acad02f8](https://mempool.space/tx/4d8a475e7a0433ef84baec9ec941342cb31d4194b42dedccdc4503e4acad02f8)

Why would anyone use this instead of P2WPKH which is both cheaper and has a larger anonymity set?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may be looking at transactions of an unknown entity dubbed "Crazy1o1". To my knowledge, it is still unknown who they are or why they are using 1-of-1 transactions, but they've been active for years. Notable mentions:

- LaurentMT first [describing and naming Crazy1o1](https://twitter.com/LaurentMT/status/1264586463536189444)
- LaurentMT analyzing some [traffic of Crazy1o1](https://twitter.com/LaurentMT/status/1264958123275681793)
- Stepan Snigirev [asking](https://twitter.com/StepanSnigirev/status/1413156991606865924) about 1-of-1 transactions
- [Crazy1o1 consolidating](https://twitter.com/ziggamon/status/1264233427840176129) 720k+ UTXOs at over 100 s/vB while the mempool was essentially empty
- On-going traffic of [1-of-1 multisig transactions](https://mempool.observer/monitor/?filter=WD0xLW9mLTE%3D)
- [Crazy1o1](https://oxt.me/entity/tiid/3498542669) on OXT.me

Update: LaurentMT suggests that Crazy1o1 is a [“Crypto and Forex broker named KOT4X”](https://twitter.com/LaurentMT/status/1577023660153413632)